# How can I filter (dplyr) on the same dataset twice in a 'for' loop? R

Tags: r, loops

I have a dataset that looks like this:

`Hospital.Name                            State  heart attack
1     SOUTHEAST ALABAMA MEDICAL CENTER    AL          14.3
2        MARSHALL MEDICAL CENTER SOUTH    AL          18.5
3       ELIZA COFFEE MEMORIAL HOSPITAL    AL          18.1
4             MIZELL MEMORIAL HOSPITAL    AL Not Available
5          CRENSHAW COMMUNITY HOSPITAL    AL Not Available
6        MARSHALL MEDICAL CENTER NORTH    AL Not Available
7                    ST VINCENT'S EAST    AL          17.7
8       DEKALB REGIONAL MEDICAL CENTER    AL          18.0
9        SHELBY BAPTIST MEDICAL CENTER    AL          15.9
10    CALLAHAN EYE FOUNDATION HOSPITAL    AL Not Available
11      HELEN KELLER MEMORIAL HOSPITAL    AL          19.6
12                 DALE MEDICAL CENTER    AL          17.3
13             CHEROKEE MEDICAL CENTER    AL Not Available
14        BAPTIST MEDICAL CENTER SOUTH    AL          17.8
15       JACKSON HOSPITAL & CLINIC INC    AL          17.5
16  GEORGE H. LANIER MEMORIAL HOSPITAL    AL          15.4
17               ELBA GENERAL HOSPITAL    AL Not Available
18 EAST ALABAMA MEDICAL CENTER AND SNF    AL          16.3
19                    WEDOWEE HOSPITAL    AL Not Available
20      UNIVERSITY OF ALABAMA HOSPITAL    AL          15.0`

The goal is to retrieve the hospital name, for a given rank of hospital on 'heart attack' for every state. For example, here I am trying to retrieve the hospital name for the lowest score (rank=1) in the heart attack column, for every state in a data frame.

This is my attempt:

```
stateVec <- unique(df$State)
outcome <- 'heart attack'
name <- c()
st <- c()
stateVec <- c()
rank <- 1
for (i in 1:length(stateVec)) {
    k <- stateVec[i]
    df1 <- dplyr::filter(df, State==k)
    rankVec <- unique(df[[outcome]])
    rankVec <- sort(rankVec[rankVec != 'Not Available'])
    key <- rankVec[rank]
    df1 <- dplyr::filter(df1, get(outcome, envir = as.environment(df))==key)
    df1 <- df1[order(df$Hospital.Name), , drop = F]
    d <- df1[1,]
    name <- d$Hospital.Name
    st <- k
    return(data.frame(st, name))
    }
```

I receive the following error:

```
Error in filter_impl(.data, quo) : Result must have length 98, not 4706
```

I've tried recreating the problem with the mtcars dataset, and don't get the same error. Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for.

```
desired_rank <- 1
df %>% 
  filter(!is.na(heart.attack)) %>% 
  group_by(State) %>% 
  arrange(heart.attack) %>% 
  slice(desired_rank) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

1. It remove's NA values for `heart.attack`;
2. Then groups by State;
3. Then sorts ascending on `heart.attack`;
4. Then returns the first hospital (so the hospital with lowest `heart.attack` value).

The output is a data.frame.

Comment: I should have been clearer. Apologies. How would I retrieve the hospital name if I wanted it for a different rank? Here rank=1, since lowest score means best hospital. But, what if I wanted the rank to be 2 or 3?

Comment: You can fill in the desired rank in `slice()`. I edited this in the answer.